# Can we use PJSIP/Siphon in our SIP Voip App

Tags: ios, sip, pjsip

We are working on a commercial VOIP application based on SIP. We have found PJSIP/Siphon and able to compile for iOS 7. And it's working fine for us. So, our doubt is if we can use this in our app and deploy the app to app store.

Thanks.

Comment: yep, you can, that is our application which uses the PJSIP, and that is live in the AppStore: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/avaya-hospitality-portal/id661073658?mt=8

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We just want to make sure our efforts will not go in vain working on PJSIP. Now we will work around the PJSIP to integrate all our requirements.

Comment: @user1873452 i am also working on commercial VOIP app based on SIP. Can u please share with me the steps u followed for compiling successfully for ios7 simulator and ios7 device?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you have an open-source product you can use it in the AppStore.

If you do not share your source code you must buy a license from Teluu before you launch it in the AppStore.

If you use Siphon, you will need to look at their license terms as well before pushing it to the AppStore.

Otherwise they can sue you and get your app kicked out of the stores and it can become a very expensive process for you.